# How does Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm work in the context of tangle?

Tags: iri-node

I read that the algorithm will kick off after Coordinator is shut down. How does this algorithm work?

Comment: This is a question for google and not for StackExchange

Comment: Google has literally a widget which provides basic information from Wikipedia when this title is put into Google.

Comment: Having an explanation of this algorithm in the context of the tangle can be interesting.

Comment: It is explained in Section 4.1 of the Tangle WP.